# How to read .mod file in R?

Tags: r

I have stored the model in .mod extension. 
Now I have to read the file.
Tried installing ProTrackR package and read using read.module.
But not able to read the file.

Comment: In its current format, this question is likely to get closed as too broad.  You need to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example - one that people can see what code you're running, and what errors it generates.  The guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) refers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
read.module(filename, ignore.validity = F)
```